# How to exit Windows Python in Cygwin

Tags: python, cygwin

I have installed Python with the Windows binaries, so I need to type `python -i` to start Python in Cygwin. And when I exit it I need to write `exit()`. It is just a minor issue, but I still would like to know if it possible to fix it so I can exit using `Ctrl+Z` like I do when I run Python in `cmd`

Comment: Try using `Ctrl-D` to exit instead.

Comment: Already tried it, and it does not work either

Answer (score 2):

To run Windows Python from within Cygwin, **always do this:**

```
$ cygstart python
```

**Never do this:**

```
$ python -i
```

This extends to Windows IPython as well. **Always do this:**

```
$ cygstart ipython
```

**Never do this:**

```
$ ipython -i
```

Before we get to why, however, let's talk `${PATH}`.

### Python and `${Path}`: Together at Last!

The above answer assumes the `python` in your current `${PATH}` to be the native Windows rather than Cygwin-installed version of Python. If the latter is the case, the absolute path of your Windows Python must be explicitly passed to `cygstart`. For example:

```
$ cygstart /cygdrive/c/Miniconda3/python.exe
```

If you run Windows Python with any semblance of frequency, you probably want to make *that* your definitive `python`. If you installed a popular Python distribution (e.g., Anaconda, Miniconda, Enthought Canopy), this means you. To do so, prepend `${PATH}` by the absolute path of the directory containing `python.exe` on shell startup (e.g., in `~/.bashrc`). For example:

```
# Stash this somewhere.
export PATH="/cygdrive/c/Miniconda3:${PATH}"
```

### What's Wrong with `python -i` or `cmd.exe`, Chummer?

On espying yet another well-intended recommendation to run Windows Python via either `python -i` from within Cygwin *or* `python` from within a non-Cygwin terminal, I only shake the head.

**No. No. No.** In both cases, you're doing it wrong.

In the case of running `python -i` from within Cygwin, you lose sane keyboard bindings (e.g., <*Up*> and <*Down*> to cycle through the REPL history, <*Ctrl-D*> to terminate the REPL) and, perhaps more importantly, output buffering.

In the case of running `python` from within a non-Cygwin terminal, you lose Cygwin. You use Cygwin for a reason – presumably because you prefer POSIX-compatibility and everything that entails (e.g., a sane shell) to the conventional Windows alternative.

### What's So Smoking Hot about `cygstart`, Anyway?

There's no reason to drop Cygwin. There's *every* reason, however, to run a native Windows application and hence Windows Python from within Cygwin as a native Windows process rather than as a POSIX-compatible Cygwin process. Which it's not.

**Enter `cygstart`.**

This standard Cygwin utility is (rather confusingly) [overloaded](https://gist.github.com/charlesroper/317713) to interface in a variety of marginally interesting ways with native Windows applications, paths, and URIs. For our purpose, passing `cygstart` the name of a command in the current `${PATH}` runs that command as a native Windows process, preserving Windows shell syntax and semantics in the presence of Cygwin.

### tl;dr

Native Windows applications – including Windows Python and IPython – should *always* be run from within Cygwin via the `cygstart` command.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the difference between Cygwin terminal emulators (MinTTY etc), which try to act like Linux terminals for the benefit of native Cygwin apps, and the Windows cmd terminal emulator. Because MinTTY handles signals differently, it won't pass <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> as an EOF signal to Windows Python, while <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> isn't handled by Windows Python at all.

The solution is to stick to using Windows Python in Windows terminal emulators (ie the cmd terminal emulator, which is the same one as you get if you start Windows Python from the Start Menu or similar), and to install Cygwin Python and use that from Cygwin terminal emulators. That way each will receive and handle the relevant signals correctly.